# Can I run only Memgraph Lab in Docker?

Tags: memgraphdb

Is it possible to run only Memgraph Lab when running Memgraph Platform image? That might help me with the deployment, where I would have database deployed separately from its visual user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can [run only the Lab](https://github.com/memgraph/memgraph-platform#lab-only) with the following command:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 memgraph/memgraph-platform -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord-lab-only.conf
```

If needed, you can also provide Lab configuration params, such as:

```
# Max limit for the Cypher query
APP_CYPHER_QUERY_MAX_LEN=5000
# Max limit for the query module name
APP_MODULE_NAME_MAX_LEN=1000
# Max limit for the query module content
APP_MODULE_CONTENT_MAX_LEN=50000
# Max name for the stream name
APP_STREAM_NAME_MAX_LEN=500
```

Hence, if you'd like to set a limit to the length of your Cypher query, this is how you'd run Memgraph Lab:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -e APP_CYPHER_QUERY_MAX_LEN=10000 memgraph/memgraph-platform -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord-lab-only.conf
```